# Quali sono le regole per la formazione di aggettivi in -abile e -ibile?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Mi domandavo se è possibile formare aggettivi in -abile e -ibile da qualsiasi verbo transitivo o se ci sono regole da osservare. Vedo che i vocabolari riportano molti di questi aggettivi come voci a parte, anche per i verbi regolari, e quando non ne trovo uno mi chiedo sempre se sia comunque legittimo usarlo, come per le altre forme verbali di cui sul vocabolario si trova solo l'infinito presente. Oppure è come inventarsi le parole?

Answer (score 6):

L'italiano, come le altre lingue vive, è molto generoso quanto all'“invenzione” delle parole. Non c'è un limite netto fra parole “vere” e parole “inventate”, né tanto meno un canone fissato da dizionari o altro (al contrario, sono i dizionari ad aggiornarsi periodicamente per accogliere le novità).

Ciò detto, “-abile” e “-ibile” sono, insieme a “-evole”, due dei più fertili fra i suffissi aggettivali deverbali (cioè suffissi che si uniscono alla radice di un verbo per creare aggettivi: attenzione, gli aggettivi risultanti non sono forme verbali). Derivano dagli analoghi latini *-ābilis* e *-ĭbilis*; il primo si usa con verbi della prima coniugazione e il secondo con gli altri verbi.

Come hai visto, si ottengono aggettivi che indicano una possibilità o un'opportunità e, se aggiunti a verbi transitivi, hanno senso passivo (“amare” > “amabile” = che può essere amato, che è degno di essere amato). Per i verbi intransitivi, il senso ovviamente è attivo: “deperire” > “deperibile” = che può deperire.

Puoi trovare più lumi nel paragrafo XV.55 dell'*Italiano* di Serianni, ma più in generale potrai trovare interessante tutto il cap. XV, che tratta della formazione delle parole, e in particolare di meccanismi, come questo della suffissazione, che sono “a metà tra lessico e grammatica”, cioè appunto a metà fra le due posizioni del tuo dubbio: non si ottengono vere e proprie parole nuove, mai sentite (come invece, per esempio, adottando parole da altre lingue), ma non si tratta nemmeno di semplici regole morfologiche come quelle che permettono di formare i vari tempi e modi di un verbo partendo dall'infinito.